# What does the capital letter 'J' mean in cost function J(θ)?

Tags: machine-learning

I saw many people using 'J(θ)' to represent cost function, what does the capital letter 'J' exactly mean?

Comment: Consider giving context/link/equation, it could help people to answer. Still, I guess @Thomas I right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know it comes from the Jacobian Matrix which represents the derivitave in all the directions. And because it has become the standard in machine learning it sticks.

Answer (score 2):

But in machine learning J(theta) is not a matrix, it is a multidimensionnal real function that we want to minimize.

So the letter J may well be a reference to Jacobi, but why it is used to name a cost function still remains a mystery, that no MOOC nor blog has revealed.